# Proper Way to Read a Data File in Javascript/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I have a flat data file in the form of xml, but there isn't a real Windows viewer for the file, currently. I decided to create a simple application with Node-WebKit, just for basic viewing - the data file won't need to be written to by the application.

My problem is, I don't know the proper way to read a large file. The data file is a backup of phone SMS's and MMS's, and the MMS entries contain Base64 image strings where applicable - so, the file gets pretty big, with large amounts of images (generallly, around 250mb). I didn't create/format the original data in the file, so I can't modify it's structure.

So, the question is - assuming I already have a way to parse the XML into JavaScript objects, should I, 
a) Parse the entire file when the application is first run, storing an array of objects in memory for the duration of the applications lifetime, or 
b) Read through the entire file each time I want to extract a conversation (all of the messages with a specific outgoing or incoming number), and only store that data in memory, or 
c) Employ some alternate, more efficient, solution that I don't know about yet.

Comment: Is this happening in the front end or server side?

Comment: Can you create a server side script (like perl) to break the file into chunks for your front end?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear - the entire application is on the client-side, via node-webkit - so, data transfer from a server isn't really applicable - the file will be opened from the local filesystem by the user. I'm more so wondering if so much data stored in the memory would lead to bad preformance, or if the process of reading through a file that large so many times (each time I wanted to extract a conversation) would be wasteful.

Comment: How do you want to display the data, just the xml tree or actually process the elements in it?

Comment: 250mb is not that big, but this depends on the device/hardware.  It certainly would be a concern 10 years ago, but shouldn't be today for non-mobile devices.  I'm not as familiar with node-webkit vs node.js.  If the person is running node.js, then essentially they are running this server-side, right?

Comment: I'll end up actually processing the elements - I already have code to process each xml element written into JS objects.

Comment: @vol7ron no, node-webkit is a bare bones "browser" featuring webkit and node.js in one process. It is meant as a "shell" to deliver HTML5-NodeJS apps as stand alone applications.

Comment: @LJ_1102 so you don't have to install Node.js / npm locally to run them?  Is this the same thing that hta was supposed to be 20 years ago?

Comment: @JakePowell i would go with approach b, just parse the subtrees into memory when required to, build your ui so that you have something like an conversation overview, where you need to select the conversation, then load/process the required conversation data, preferably non blocking in a webworker.

Comment: @vol7ron i dont know what hta was/is. A "finished" node-webkit application is just a stand alone executable with an appended zip file containing the files needed by the application(think htdocs here). Its possible to access webkit window/dom api as well as "native" node.js api from the application code.

Comment: @LJ_1102: hta = HTML Applications.  Built by Microsoft for quick applications using HTML markup and a scripting language (VBScript/Jscript).

Comment: What about thoughts on Web SQL or Local Storage?

Comment: Well you can use any browser feature that a webkit browser has, like LocalStorage etc. as well as all node.js functionality. But i think this is not a problem the OP has, since the files are local as well as the application.

Comment: @LJ_1102 Ok, just to prevent storing the entire files contents in memory?

Comment: @vol7ron WebSQL or Local Storage? So, parse the xml into a temporary database format, then extract it for viewing from that?

Comment: more to prevent processing >50MB of data at once, and possibly freezing the application for a few seconds, saving memory is just a nice side effect. I do not see any reason to parse it into WebSQL or LocalStorage.

Comment: @LJ_1102 Makes sense - so, you don't think that reading the file each time a conversation is selected would be problematic? Or, should I copy the file contents to a temporary file and parse that?

Comment: Depending on the xml structure you may need to parse the whole file anyway to get all the information you need to build the "overview", so "processing" means just the creation of all the markup, image parsing etc. Depending on how you parse the xml (using DOMFragment or a library) you may be able to delay the parsing of the "sub-nodes" which would be even better in terms of performance and memory management.

Comment: @vol7ron 250MB is absolutely massive depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: @Brad it's big, but I wouldn't say massive.  Perhaps I'm used to working with TB/PB sets for too long, but yes, regarding its uses the what and how are very important.

Comment: @LJ_1102 the point is to also keep it cached for the next time it's opened. As time progresses, I imagine there will be more messages and the need to trace back and search even more amounts of data.  250MB is small now but will probably grow.  Like you said, the whole file will need to be read anyhow, unless there is already an index, manifest, or schema file that accompanies it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60305/discussion-on-question-by-jake-powell-proper-way-to-read-a-data-file-in-javascri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your XML data into an SQLite db. SQLite is NOT memory based by default. Query the db when you need the data, problem solved :)

Comment: Not memory based? Meaning the data won't be persistently stored, and should be released at the application's close?

Comment: Means that it doesn't store the whole dataset on the memory, which is what you said you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Ok, makes sense - what would be the best place to store the database?

Comment: Does not matter. What matters is that it is somewhere on your client 's computer.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll try a temporary sqlite database then - all the benefits of SQL along with temporary, easily-accessible storage.